# Installation Trouble with the Ubuntu 14.04 iso

Tags: dual-boot

I burned the disk with the Ubuntu 14.04 iso image, booted up from that disk, and started the installation process when prompted to. But as soon as I got to the part where it asked about the installation option, it said I didn't have an operating system. I already have windows 8 and want to install Ubuntu alongside it on a separate hard drive. How shall I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: From your BIOS, see if you can boot your Ubuntu Live USB or CD in EFI mode; this may allow the installer to see your Wundows EFI installation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two options.

1. There is usually a third choice where you can partition your hard drive with gparted during the installation. Then, you can install Ubuntu on the new partition.
2. You can just create a new Ubuntu install disk.

Good Luck!